# How to set valid rule for boolean field in select input?

Tags: laravel

In laravel 8 I added new boolean field :

```
$table->boolean( 'is_opened' )->default(false)->after('active');
```

and having array of labels :

```
$htmlBlockIsOpenedValueArray = [0 => 'Is not opened', 1 => 'Is opened'];
```

I have select input defined :

```
<select name="is_opened" id="is_opened" class="form-control">
    <option value=""> -Select is opened-</option>
    @foreach($htmlBlockIsOpenedValueArray as $is_opened => $value)
        <option value="{{ $is_opened }}" @if (old('is_opened')?old('is_opened'):$htmlBlock->is_opened) == $is_opened) selected @endif>{{ $value }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

But it does not work correctly, if on saving 'Is not opened'/0/false is selected, as label “-Select is opened-” is visible.
My condition block is not very simple, as I try to show cuurent value in case of validation error.

Which condition can be valid here ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're using your old value as a `boolean`. A 0 is considered `false` in php. Therefore, your code will not function until you select 1.

However, you can pass a default so you don't have to perform an if statement:

```php
old('is_opened', $htmlBlock->is_opened)
```

P.S., you're currently not strictly comparing types. This, in your case, is a good thing, since the old values will be of type `string`, even though your original key is an `integer`. It's just something to keep in mind.